# How to resolve header errors in POST Request?

Tags: java, angular, post, servlets

I am working on a website that uses Angular, Java Servlet APIs, and MySQL DB. I'm observing this error on sending a POST request. Can someone help.
[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MqNF5.png)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: @StephenC Thanks for letting know. Will rectify in future posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question could have been more clear. Nonetheless, let me answer from my understanding. Whenever you make an HTTP request to an API, the first request that is sent by the browser is the preflight request (OPTIONS request). This method requests permitted communication options for a given URL. You can try setting the headers by handling the OPTIONS request. That is, you can handle the preflight request with the help of the doOptions() method.

```
    protected void doOptions(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
              throws ServletException, IOException {
          setAccessControlHeaders(response);
          response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK  );
    }
     
    private void setAccessControlHeaders(HttpServletResponse resp) {
          resp.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
          resp.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS");
          resp.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With");
          
     }
```